# Rails link_to destroy a nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a nested resource attachments and I want to create a `link_to` to destroy/delete the attachment. Here's what I have, but it is posting as a GET versus a PUT:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Attachment", project_thread_attachment_path(@attachment.thread.project.id, @attachment.thread.id, @attachment.id), :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this attachment?", :method => :delete, :action => "destroy" %>
```

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use the following by itself (remove the :action => 'destroy' part). Also, the request should be a DELETE request, not a PUT request:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Attachment", project_thread_attachment_path(@attachment.thread.project.id, @attachment.thread.id, @attachment.id), :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this attachment?", :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: Cool thanks but I just checked the logs it is still doing a GET

Comment: That's odd. Did you try flipping :method and :confirm around? Which log does it appear as a GET request in? Do you see a parameter named _method in the call?

Comment: @Pan Thomakos, Yeah, what is the difference between having the arguments in an array, like in Gerry's answer , vs having them in a raw, comma-separated list of arguments like in this answer?

Comment: A comma separated list like `function(a,b,c)` passes 3 arguments, namely `a`, `b` and `c`, to `function`. An array like `function([a,b,c])` passes 1 argument, namely the array `[a,b,c]` to `function`.

Answer (score 16):

Try

```
link_to "Delete Attachment", [@attachment.thread.project,@attachment.thread,@attachment], :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete
```

Does it work?

Comment: This worked great for me, can you explain why?  Why the brackets instead of foo_path(parent_of_foo,foo)?

Comment: @TJSherrill the brackets is an array of the nested records, which is then "processed" by Rails to compute a path for all the given nested records (according to your routes). In this case the first element of the array is a Project, second a Thread and third an Attachment. Rails "guess" that an Attachment belongs to a Thread which belongs to a Project, computing a path with these nested records: `project`, then `thread`, then `attachment`, which leads to the helper : `project_thread_attachment_path`

Comment: @MrYoshiji:
I had this solution working but than added a scope with the :as  in the routes set to "admin" so that the path noch has a prefix called "admin_". Now the path generater doesn't work anymore. What do I have to change to add a scope to this solution?

Comment: I found the answer by myself:
I just have to ad the :admin symbol to the array as the first entry like this:
`[:admin, @attachment.thread.project, @attachment.thread, @attachment]`